# Arduino IDE doesn't run on Arch linux

Tags: linux, ide, arduino

When I run arduino in console I get:

```
[lukas@lu arduino]$ arduino
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'r'
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:769)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:576)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:501)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:476)
    at processing.app.tools.Archiver.init(Archiver.java:59)
    at processing.app.Editor.createToolMenuItem(Editor.java:859)
    at processing.app.Editor.addInternalTools(Editor.java:885)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:660)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:476)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:205)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:704)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:669)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:565)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:305)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:194)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1041)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:373)
    at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.add(JPopupMenu.java:281)
    at javax.swing.JMenu.add(JMenu.java:579)
    at processing.app.Editor.addInternalTools(Editor.java:885)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:660)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:476)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:205)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:704)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:669)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:565)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:305)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:194)
```

and nothing happens after 10 minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo pacman -S xrandr`?

Comment: It isn't a problem. I'm using xinerama. When I disable xinerama I have still problem with running arduino.

Comment: `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing` - it appears xrandr *is* your problem, install `libxrandr`.

Comment: I am happy for this to reside here, after all questions about **development tools** and how to get them running are on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running arduino I must change locale to en_US.UTF-8

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```